# Complex accumulo queries

Tags: java, accumulo

Given an key, or a list of keys, what is the method to construct a complex server side filter for accumulo.

EXAMPLE: `filter a` OR `filter b`?

EXAMPLE: `filter a` AND `filter b` OR `filter c` AND `filter d`?

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into doing a custom iterator?  Typically they are per table and work over the entire table, but can be used for filtering and aggregation in Accumulo.

http://accumulo.apache.org/notable_features.html - Basic Accumulo Explanation of an Iterator.

http://accumulo.net/iterators/overview - Explanation of how Accumulo Iterators work and includes and example with explanations.

Comment: I was hoping that there was a "built-in" accumulo filter/iterator for chaining filters...

Comment: Couldn't you see if you could write a filter that calls those other filters in succession?